# Textbox difficulty

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get data from two `TextBox` fields and add them to a third `TextBox` using a simple button. It can be done easily.

Where I got stuck is a scenario like this. The button may first be disabled as nothing is provided in the text fields, and get enabled as the user type any digit in the text field.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (textBox1.Text != null)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
       int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
       int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
       textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your 'enabling code' to a private method. Call this method from on update handlers on the textboxes.

Comment: If you're happy with an answer please accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick (but it's not very elegant):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SetButtonEnableState();
    }

    private void SetButtonEnableState()
    {
        button1.Enabled = !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text));

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetButtonEnableState();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetButtonEnableState();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In your case you might want to check if the textbox values are actually int values and if this is the case, then enable the button. So why not update the method above with this?

```
    private void SetButtonEnableState()
    {
        int n;

        button1.Enabled = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out n) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why did you put your codes under `Form1`, the code will just activate after the form has loaded. To fix this you first need to create a `textBox1_TextChange` Event. Don't forget to disable the button in the property. `enabled=false`
Like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You place the code you write on that event block.

To trigger the button when the 2 textBoxes already has numbers. use this:

select the two textboxes and on the event tab beside the properties look for `KeyPress` then name it as `numbersTB_KeyPress`

```
private void numbersTB_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender as TextBox != null)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                else
                    button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```